# Apply conditional formatting to the top four values in a range

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, worksheet-function

I have a range of cells B11:B18 and I want to conditionally format them to highlight ONLY the top four values. I have tried different formulas I found online but they rank ALL eight cells!

Comment: Thank you, anonymous rabbit! It works well if I apply one color. If I want to apply the color scale, can I make the scale stop at 4 instead of all 8 cells? For my purposes, one color is OK, but I'm getting ambitious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(B11=LARGE($B$11:$B$18,{1,2,3,4})))
```

Apply to `B11:B18`

Comment: It would help to maybe explain a bit about what your formula does. This will help folks who have this problem in the future understand what's going on with the answer.

Comment: I will be tallying municipal votes as they are reported by the different precincts. For races such as at-large councilors, only 4 candidates out of 8 win, and in School Committee 3 out of 6.

Answer (score 0):

Please select B11:B18 and apply a **Custom formula is** of:

```
=rank(B11,B$11:B$18)<5
```

with formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

[RANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094098)

Perhaps the formula you tried should have had rows anchored.